# Django SearchFilter is displaying all the data when the search field is empty

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I have implemented search feature using Django SearchFilter DRF which is perfectly working but the issue is I don't want to display all the query when I pass nothing in the search field. It is by default returning all the query. I don't know how to handle it.

views.py

```
    class EventSearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
          permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
          queryset = Event.objects.all()
          search_fields = ["name", "description","content"]
          filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
          serializer_class = EventSearchSerializer
          pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
```

When I search for fields "name", "description" it is working fine but when I search nothing and hit the url without search fields by default it is returning all the query, but I want to display nothing.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override `get_queryset` method to check if `query_params` contains data or not:

```
class EventSearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)    
    search_fields = ["name", "description","content"]
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    serializer_class = EventSearchSerializer
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.query_params:    
            return Event.objects.all()
    return Event.objects.none()
```

Answer (score 2):

The other way its use Filter class. Just define it anywhere.

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class ContentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(required=True)

    class Meta:
    model = <your_model>
    fields = ['name']
```

Than you can add it in your view:

```
filterset_class = ContentFilter
```

Now your name parameter will be required and no one can fetch you request without it.
This is better way because if User forget to send parameter he get the error message and not a blank response.